# Validating and baking open badges

Tags: json, openbadge

I've been trying to generate open badges for a while, but so far none of them will validate or bake using the online tools.

I've tried a variety of different combinations. Here's the one I'm using currently (sites removed due to being preproduction sites) :

On the site at http://example.org/badge/5ab0d10a6a02f :

```
{
    "@context":"https://w3id.org/openbadges/v1",
    "type":"Assertion",
    "id":"http://example.org/badge/5ab0d10a6a02f",
    "uid":"5ab0d10a6a02f",
    "recipient":
    {
        "type":"email",
        "identity":"email@example.org",
        "hashed":false
    },
    "issuedOn":1521564293,
    "badge":"http://example.org/badge-class.json",
    "verify":
    {
        "type":"hosted",
        "url":"http://example.org/badge-issuer.json"
    }
}
```

On the site at http://example.org/badge-class.json :

```
{
    "@context": "https://w3id.org/openbadges/v1",
    "id": "http://example.org/badge-class.json",
    "type": "BadgeClass",
    "name": "Badge",
    "description": "Description",
    "image": "http://example.org/badge.png",
    "criteria": "http://example.org/criteria",
    "issuer": "http://example.org/badge-issuer.json"
}
```

and at http://example.org/badge-issuer.json :

```
{
    "@context": "https://w3id.org/openbadges/v1",
    "id": "http://example.org/badge-issuer.json",
    "type": "Issuer",
    "name": "Name",
    "url": "http://www.example.org/",
    "telephone" : "xxxxxxxxx",
    "description" : "description",
    "image" : "http://www.example.org/logo.png",
    "email" : "email@example.org"
}
```

Once properly hosted on a real site, I tried to validate and bake it, but I get the following errors :

For the [validators](http://validator.openbadges.org/) :

```
{
  "status": "invalid",
  "reason": "Remote assertion must match local assertion",
  "error": {
    "message": "Remote assertion must match local assertion",
    "code": "deep-equal",
    "extra": {
      "local": {
        "@context": "https://w3id.org/openbadges/v1",
        "type": "Assertion",
        "id": "http://example.org/badge/5ab0d10a6a02f",
        "uid": "5ab0d10a6a02f",
        "recipient": {
          "type": "email",
          "identity": "email@example.org",
          "hashed": false
        },
        "issuedOn": 1521564293,
        "badge": "http://example.org/badge-class.json",
        "verify": {
          "type": "hosted",
          "url": "http://example.org/badge-issuer.json"
        }
      },
      "hosted": {
        "@context": "https://w3id.org/openbadges/v1",
        "id": "http://example.org/badge-issuer.json",
        "type": "Issuer",
        "name": "Name",
        "url": "http://example.org/",
        "telephone": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "description": "description",
        "image": "http://example.org/logo.png",
        "email": "email@example.org"
      }
    }
  },
  "info": {
    "raw": {
      "input": {
        "@context": "https://w3id.org/openbadges/v1",
        "type": "Assertion",
        "id": "http://example.org/badge/5ab0d10a6a02f",
        "uid": "5ab0d10a6a02f",
        "recipient": {
          "type": "email",
          "identity": "email@example.org",
          "hashed": false
        },
        "issuedOn": 1521564293,
        "badge": "http://example.org/badge-class.json",
        "verify": {
          "type": "hosted",
          "url": "http://example.org/badge-issuer.json"
        }
      }
    },
    "parse": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "hosted",
      "scheme": "1.1.0-hosted",
      "assertion": {
        "@context": "https://w3id.org/openbadges/v1",
        "type": "Assertion",
        "id": "http://example.org/badge/5ab0d10a6a02f",
        "uid": "5ab0d10a6a02f",
        "recipient": {
          "type": "email",
          "identity": "email@example.org",
          "hashed": false
        },
        "issuedOn": 1521564293,
        "badge": "http://example.org/badge-class.json",
        "verify": {
          "type": "hosted",
          "url": "http://example.org/badge-issuer.json"
        }
      }
    },
    "assertion": {
      "@context": "https://w3id.org/openbadges/v1",
      "type": "Assertion",
      "id": "http://example.org/badge/5ab0d10a6a02f",
      "uid": "5ab0d10a6a02f",
      "recipient": {
        "type": "email",
        "identity": "email@example.org",
        "hashed": false
      },
      "issuedOn": 1521564293,
      "badge": "http://example.org/badge-class.json",
      "verify": {
        "type": "hosted",
        "url": "http://example.org/badge-issuer.json"
      }
    },
    "guid": "38edfd9e94b1bda73a0283a02425710508e7713dc5eb78a65f93a57b67460324",
    "badge": {
      "@context": "https://w3id.org/openbadges/v1",
      "id": "http://example.org/badge-class.json",
      "type": "BadgeClass",
      "name": "Badge",
      "description": "Description",
      "image": "http://example.org/badge.png",
      "criteria": "http://example.org/criteria",
      "issuer": "http://example.org/badge-issuer.json"
    },
    "issuer": {
      "@context": "https://w3id.org/openbadges/v1",
      "id": "http://example.org/badge-issuer.json",
      "type": "Issuer",
      "name": "Name",
      "url": "http://www.example.org/",
      "telephone": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "description": "description",
      "image": "http://www.example.org/logo.png",
      "email": "email@example.org"
    },
    "objects": true,
    "recipient": true,
    "jsonld_expanded": {
      "https://w3id.org/openbadges#badge": [
        {
          "@id": "http://example.org/badge-class.json"
        }
      ],
      "@id": "http://example.org/badge/5ab0d10a6a02f",
      "https://w3id.org/openbadges#issueDate": [
        {
          "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime",
          "@value": 1521564293
        }
      ],
      "https://w3id.org/openbadges#recipient": [
        {
          "https://w3id.org/openbadges#hashed": [
            {
              "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean",
              "@value": false
            }
          ],
          "https://w3id.org/openbadges#identityHash": [
            {
              "@value": "email@example.org"
            }
          ],
          "@type": [
            "http://schema.org/email"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "@type": [
        "https://w3id.org/openbadges#Assertion"
      ],
      "https://w3id.org/openbadges#uid": [
        {
          "@value": "5ab0d10a6a02f"
        }
      ],
      "https://w3id.org/openbadges#verify": [
        {
          "@type": [
            "https://w3id.org/openbadges#HostedBadge"
          ],
          "http://schema.org/url": [
            {
              "@id": "http://example.org/badge-issuer.json"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "extensions": {},
    "extension_properties": true,
    "extension_schemas": {},
    "unrevoked": "Only required for signed verification",
    "signature": "Only required for signed verification"
  }
}
```

Using the [baker](http://bakery.openbadges.org/) :

```
Could not parse json: Unexpected token <
```

Using the [baker API](http://backpack.openbadges.org/baker?assertion=) :

```
{
    "message":"could not get assertion: invalid JSON",
    "stack":"Error: could not get assertion: invalid JSON
        at makeError (/app/lib/analyze-assertion.js:6:26)
        at Request._callback (/app/lib/analyze-assertion.js:31:23)
        at Request.self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
        at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1126:10)
        at Request.emit (events.js:95:17)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1046:12)
        at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
        at _stream_readable.js:944:16",
    "code":"parse"
}
```

What part of this badge is causing the issues?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the last eight (8) lines of the badge assertion file at http://example.org/badge/5ab0d10a6a02f should be:

```
{

    ...
    ... 
    "badge":"http://example.org/badge-class.json",
    "issuer":"http://example.org/badge-issuer.json",
    "verify":
    {
        "type":"hosted",
        "url":"http://example.org/badge/5ab0d10a6a02f/THIS-BADGE-ASSERTION-FILE.json"
    }
}
```

where `THIS-BADGE-ASSERTION-FILE.json` is the badge assertion `JSON` file and is precisely the file whose contents we are modifying.  That is to say, the "verify" URL should point to the badge assertion `JSON` file (that resides within the folder http://example.org/badge/5ab0d10a6a02f/) and not to the `badge-issuer.json` file which is the badge issuer `JSON` file.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Step 2: Award the Badge](https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges-backpack/wiki/New-Issuers:-Give-Yourself-a-Badge#step-2-award-the-badge)  from the [Wiki pages of Mozilla Open Badges Backpack on GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges-backpack/wiki)).